# Iterate Map Inside List in order to display the values as row in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

i need to display the value which is inside `Map`, and Map is inside `List`.
Right now, My values are displaying but in column manner (as shown in sceenshot). not in row manner, I want to display all the values as column manner

[image]

As you can see in above image, 
take first record, 
100 should be mapped with column Pay Code
BASIC PAY should be mapped with Description
25300 should be mapped with Amount
and 2, is useless, I don't want this to display it anymore.

my service method which fetches the data:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> searchPayCodeByempCode(String tabSuffix, String empCode, String yyyyMm) {
    MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    String tableName = "Salary_detail_report_082018";
    String query = "SELECT "
            + " DISTINCT PAY_CODE, "
            + " PAY_CODE_DESC, "
            + " AMOUNT, "
            + " row_number() over (Order by EMP_CODE ) AS ROW_NUM "
            + " FROM " + tableName
            + " WHERE EMP_CODE=" + empCode
            + " AND YYYYMM=" + yyyyMm
            + " AND PAY_CODE NOT IN (997,998,999) "
            + " ORDER BY PAY_CODE ASC ";
    List<Map<String, Object>> employees = queryForList(query);
    if (employees != null && !employees.isEmpty()) {
        for (Map<String, Object> employee : employees) {
             System.out.println("The set is: " + employee.keySet()); 
            for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = employee.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next();
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println(key + " = " + value);
            }
        }
    }
    return employees;
```

JSP code:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer tableWidth"  role="grid" name="employeeList" id="employeeList">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th width="5%">S. No.</th>
                                        <th width="10%">Pay Code</th>
                                        <th width="15%">Description</th>
                                        <th width="10%">Amount</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <c:forEach var="map" items="${mapList}">
                                        <c:forEach var="mapEntry" items="${map}">
                                            <tr>
                                                <%--<td>test : ${mapEntry.key}</td>--%>
                                                <td>test : ${mapEntry.value}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate list items as table rows (`<tr>`) and for each row iterate map from list item as a table cell (`<td>`):

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="map" items="${mapList}">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="mapEntry" items="${map}">
                <td>${mapEntry.value}</td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

The difference is in `<tr>` position.

If you have more items in the map and want to render only first 4 you can use status var and index value to filter them:

```
<c:forEach var="mapEntry" items="${map}" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${status.index <= 4 }">
        <td>${mapEntry.value}</td>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

---

But if you have map in a bad order (for example when using `HashMap`) then it is better to render cells selectively:

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="map" items="${mapList}">
        <tr>
            <td width="5%">${map.get("ROW_NUM")}</td>
            <td width="10%">${map.get("PAY_CODE")}</td>
            <td width="15%">${map.get("PAY_CODE_DESC")}</td>
            <td width="10%">${map.get("AMOUNT")}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Comment: ohhh mate, thanks so much, this was really the silly mistake,hey one more thing how do I ignore the row number value which is also part of map value.

Comment: thanks mate, but actually i need to sort the list by PAY_CODE , so I am not go for ROW_NUM,rather that i will go for varStatus="counter"

Comment: How the list is sorted is not important for rendering in JSP, important is whether the order of map entries is fixed (then you can use first option) or not (then it is better to use second selective option). I added some updates to the answer and hope it will help to you.

Comment: you are too good mate, your solution will be helpful to all who visited this post, you provide all the possible solutions, thanks so much

Comment: what i thought before, I wanted to convert value of map inside List into the list and then pass that list to the jsp i,e List<Map<K,V>>, I want to convert V into list and pass the same inside jsp, isn't easy approach?

Comment: If you can create `List<List<V>>` just in `queryForList()` method without using `Map` it will be faster (no conversion) and less memory consuming (no keys). In JSP you can simply render that by `c:forEach`. But much better solution will be with own bean class (`Payment` for example) with properties like `code`, `description` and `amount` and then `queryForList()` will return `List<Payment>` - it will be much more readable and also fail-safe.

Comment: I do agree, but you know why I didn't adopted this solution, because there are 95 paycode in master, and I fetched the paycode in behalf of employee, now the problem is, there are 50k+ employees and paycodes vary from employee to employee, the first problem is to maintain all the 95 paycode inside bean class and its getter and setter will make it to complex, secondly how I will identify that amongs 95 paycode how much paycode fetched for specific employees.